# crf++ verbose mode in C++ API

Tags: c++, crf++

I am using CRF++ tool for CRF parsing in C++. In the crf_learn.exe, we can get the confidence measure by enabling verbose method. Is there any way we can enable that verbose method in C++ API of CRF++?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear, please give more details ! Whats this `crf_learn.exe`? Source ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I got the answer, tagger->prob(i), you can get the confidence measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

Tagger->prob(i) will get you the confidence measure of the particular label